# UIScrollView CATiledLayer Zooming Force repaint after chaning Content

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

I have a Problem with a UIScrollView CATiledLAyer stucture.

What I'm doing is showing pdf Pages in a Zommable Scrollview with CATiledLAyer. I created a PDF Search which highlights words on the pages. Now the Problem.

How can I force the unzoomed state to redraw, because I add the highlight directly on the PDF Image in the drawLayer Method. This one is called when I first see the page (where there are no Search Results) and when i'm zooming, correctly showing the highlighted words.

But in the unzoomed state it is not showing, and I cannot force the repaint of the Layer with setNeedsDisplay on the view or the layer or the scrollview.

Can Somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I need t call setNeedsDisplay on the zoomLayer. ^^